# Java - Business Service, data access objects - Should Singletons be used or not?

Tags: java, singleton

Consider a web application with business layer and data access layer. So, every request has to be passed through these two layers in order to get processed.

Since there would be frequent requests coming in, it is not wise to create a new business and data access objects to process each and every request. In this case, usually I tend to go for Singletons of business and DAO.

But I hear lot of problems in using Singleton pattern, as many suggest against the pattern (mainly because its global). In that case, what would be the correct design strategy for the scenario I described above?

Comment: You need to be careful to distinguish "singletons" (which are fine), and the "singleton design pattern" (which is a code smell). The latter is a way of implementing the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Objects should be Singleton.

You can use [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) to maintain singleton service objects for you.

Comment: what if i'm not using Spring?

Comment: @Veera, if it is manageable you should go for it, it has many advantages

Comment: well, I'm using Struts 2. I'm not sure how well these two frameworks mix up.

Comment: @Veera, Spring can be integrated with Struts, It would be good arch. to have Spring at service layer , Check this article http://www.javabeat.net/articles/70-integrating-struts-with-spring-1.html & Example here:http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-spring-integration-example/

Answer (score 2):

The usual strategy used in such cases is to write the business services and data access objects *not* as singletons but as simple POJOs. And then use a container to manage the scope of the classes. Some examples of containers are Spring and Guice. You can even write your own container if your requirements are simple.

This way you get the benefits of the singleton pattern without its disadvantages (difficult to mock and test, etc).

A simple example:

```
public class PersonService {
    public Person getPerson(String id) {
        //find and return the person
    }
}

public class PersonServiceSingletonFactory {
    private PersonService service = new PersonService();
    PersonService getInstance() {
        return service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that writing singletons on Servlet is good idea, you can create your business logic on ServletContextListener it will assure that only one instance of object will be run in container and it is thread-safe. you can access it the way @abhin4v explained. Unless you are using Spring framework this is what you need to do.

Hope it helps.